# Helping clang to do a better job without changing the code

Tags: c, optimization, clang, c11

I'm testing various with clang 7/8 and c11.

I implemented some sorting functions and started to optimize a few of them.

Network sorting function are already very simple peaces of code but I found some rewriting can provide better performances on x64 platform (not arm).

https://godbolt.org/z/uD7_DM

If we compare both assemblies. The only remarkable differences are the push instruction count and the first mov instruction structure :

```
network_sort_08_a:
    push    rbp
    push    r14
    push    rbx
    mov     esi, dword ptr [rdi]
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
    mov     edx, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
    mov     r9d, dword ptr [rdi + 12]
    mov     ebx, dword ptr [rdi + 16]
    cmp     esi, eax
    mov     ecx, eax
    cmovle  ecx, esi
```

Instead of :

```
network_sort_8_b:
    push    rbp
    push    r15
    push    r14
    push    rbx
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
    mov     edx, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
    cmp     eax, edx
    mov     ecx, edx
    cmovle  ecx, eax
    cmovge  edx, eax
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
```

I want to output the first version without rewriting the function.

Any idea of to achieve this ?

Best regards

```c
__attribute__((always_inline))
inline int min(const int a, const int b)
{
  return a < b ? a : b;
}

__attribute__((always_inline))
inline int max(const int a, const int b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

__attribute__((always_inline))
inline void network_swap(int* keys, const int key_index0, const int key_index1)
{
  const int key0 = keys[key_index0];
  const int key1 = keys[key_index1];
  const int min_key = min(key0, key1);
  const int max_key = max(key0, key1);
  keys[key_index0] = min_key;
  keys[key_index1] = max_key;
}

void network_sort_08_a(int* keys)
{
  // Resorted by dependencies
  // Serialize first reads
  const int key0 = keys[0];
  const int key1 = keys[1];
  const int key2 = keys[2];
  const int key3 = keys[3];
  const int key4 = keys[4];
  const int key5 = keys[5];
  const int key6 = keys[6];
  const int key7 = keys[7];
  keys[0] = min(key0, key1);
  keys[1] = max(key0, key1);
  keys[2] = min(key2, key3);
  keys[3] = max(key2, key3);
  keys[4] = min(key4, key5);
  keys[5] = max(key4, key5);
  keys[6] = min(key6, key7);
  keys[7] = max(key6, key7);
  network_swap(keys, 0, 2);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 3);
  network_swap(keys, 4, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 5, 7);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 2);
  network_swap(keys, 5, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 0, 4);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 7);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 5);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 4);
  network_swap(keys, 2, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 2, 4);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 5);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 4);
}

void network_sort_8_b(int* restrict keys)
{
  network_swap(keys, 0, 1);
  network_swap(keys, 2, 3);
  network_swap(keys, 0, 2);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 3);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 2);
  network_swap(keys, 4, 5);
  network_swap(keys, 6, 7);
  network_swap(keys, 4, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 5, 7);
  network_swap(keys, 5, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 0, 4);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 5);
  network_swap(keys, 1, 4);
  network_swap(keys, 2, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 7);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 6);
  network_swap(keys, 2, 4);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 5);
  network_swap(keys, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you're trying to work with in the question. Godbolt links may disappear over time.

Comment: side note: have you actually profiled and benchmarked to see if this is slow? In most cases the compiler does a pretty good job.

Comment: I profiled this on an AMD Ryzen and there were an actual gain (between 5 and 10%).

Comment: If you use ubuntu or mingw, feel free to compare https://github.com/meuns/sort-things master and network_rewrite branches.